# How to sort query filename output like Windows explorer?

Tags: oracle, order-by

i would like to order my query output the way Windows Explorer does.

First special characters like `_`, then the numbers, and the letters last.

```
_ttt.bmp
0.gif
bbb.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your NLS_SORT to PUNCTUATION or XPUNCTUATION before running the query:

`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = 'XPUNCTUATION';`